# Why do (lazy) LINQ queries "act strange" compared to strictly-evaluated lists?

Tags: c#, linq

Why does this test fail?

```
        private class TestClass
        {
            public string Property { get; set; }
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test()
        {
            var testClasses = new[] { "a", "b", "c", "d" }
                .Select(x => new TestClass());

            foreach(var testClass in testClasses)
            {
                testClass.Property = "test";
            }

            foreach(var testClass in testClasses)
            {
                Assert.That(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(testClass.Property));
            }
        }
```

The problem is obviously to do with lazy yielding in the Select statement, because if I add a .ToList() call after the Select() method, the test passes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of how LINQ works, you are actually creating **8** different versions of `TestClass` - one set of 4 per `foreach`. Essentially the same as if you had:

```
var testClasses = new[] { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
foreach(var testClass in testClasses.Select(x => new TestClass()))
{
    testClass.Property = "test";
}

foreach(var testClass in testClasses.Select(x => new TestClass()))
{
    Assert.That(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(testClass.Property));
}
```

The first set (discarded) have the property set.

By calling `ToList()` at the end of `testClasses`, you force it to store and re-use the same 4 `TestClass` instances, hence it passes.

Answer (score 2):

Every time you iterate over the `testClasses` variable, you will run the code in the `.Select()` lambda expression. The effect in your case is that the different foreach loops gets different instances of `TestClass` objects.

As you noticed yourself, sticking a `.ToList()` at the end of the query will make sure the ot is only executed once.

Answer (score 0):

It's because LINQ extension methods such as Select return `IEnumerable<T>` which are lazy. Try to be more eager:

```
var testClasses = new[] { "a", "b", "c", "d" }
    .Select(x => new TestClass())
    .ToArray();
```